# How to import a google-font into powerBI to use as a theme. The theme is a JSON file

Tags: json, powerbi, google-font-api

I am creating a theme for the corporate branding in our PowerBI reports. The issue I have is that the font I want to use isn't a default PowerBI font and I don't know how to import it either with the theme or into the software and save it. [This](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Import-custom-local-font/td-p/183753) forum suggests there is a way to import a google-font as part of theme but I can't get it working and I'm not sure where to put the code snippet.

The font I want to use is Rubik, and the JSON code I have which specifies the font is:

```
"background": "#ffffff",
"foreground": "#000000",
"tableAccent": "#FF637D",
"dataColors": [ "#003E51", "#00BFD6", "#BCBCBB", "#8AD4EB", "#575756", "#C8D308" ],    
"visualStyles": {
        "*": {
            "*": {
                "*": [
                    {
                        "fontSize": 12,
                        "fontFamily": "DIN",
                        "color": { "solid": {} }
                    }
                ],
                "general": [ { "responsive": true } ]
            }
        },
```

I think my expected outcome will be to use a code snippet like:

```
@import (less) url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
```

someone in the file then I can change "fontFamily" to "Rubik" like:

```
"fontFamily" : "Rubik",
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Power BI does not support custom fonts for standard visuals and themes. The forum post you are referring to, relates to developing a custom visual, which is a different topic than creating a Power BI theme.

If you'd like to use custom fonts in Power BI, please consider voting for that:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9007054-allow-fonts-to-be-customized

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you can use `@import ...` in your JSON file but if you have such font installed in your system as a `.ttf` file in Windows, it is possible to use it in your desktop by modifying the JSON theme file. For instance:

```
 {
        "name": "my theme",
        "dataColors": ["#568410", "#3A6108", "#70A322", "#915203", "#D79A12", "#bb7711", "#114400", "#aacc66"],
        "background":"#FFFFFF",
        "foreground": "#3A6108",
        "tableAccent": "#568410",
        "visualStyles":{
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*":  [{
                            "fontFamily": "Roboto Condensed"
                        }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```